# How can I create a virtual microphone device?

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, jack, v4l2loopback, obs-studio

I use OBS to stream into Google Meet so I can send music and a opening scene. I also use OBS option for create a virtual camera, once I use a DSRL camera and not a webcam.

The issue I need to solve right now is that I can not use my Blue Yeti on OBS and on Google Meet at the same time. If I plug it into OBS, I can't connect it into Google Meet.

Is there anyway I can plug my microphone into Google Meet and also connect it as a virtual microphone device into OBS? That way I could record on OBS, while I'm live on G-Meet.

Comment: You tagged your question with the jack audio connection kit tag. Since one of its interests is to act as a patchbay router, what about duplicating your mic output thanks to jack ? qjackctl could help you doing that graphically. A lower possibility would be to use raw alsa dsnoop plugin.

Comment: BTW I understand that what oy want is **not**  a "virtual microphone device" what you want is to duplicate the microphone output. Please orrect me if I am wrong.